# How to resolve Debian virtual package dependency error

Tags: debian, package-management, dependencies

When attempting to update a locally-maintained package on a Debian wheezy system I get the following message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 local-tenielle : Depends: perl:any which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     local-tenielle [Not Installed]
```

The control file for `local-tenielle` has as one of its dependencies `perl`. But perl *is* installed on the system, so why I am seeing a dependency error?

Comment: As root, try `apt-get install -f` to fix dependencies and `dpkg --configure -a` to configure packages that might not have been configured properly (due to an error during installation maybe).

Comment: Broco: thanks for the suggestion but, unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: That's weird. Do you have a self-compiled perl package installed or did you use a third-party packet source?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I built the Debian package against sid but uploaded it into the wheezy repository. For many packages this might work, but for this package in the `Depends:` control file field I have `${perl:Depends}`. When you build a package against wheezy `${perl:Depends}` turns into `perl` but when you build against sid it turns into `perl:any`. There is no `perl:any` package in wheezy. Thus the complaint.

To fix it, I did what I should have done from the start: build the package against sid and then backport to wheezy.